# How do I use my Samsung S7 as a display for my Raspberry Pi 3 B without WiFi?

Tags: display, android

The title explains my question. I need to use my S7 as a display for my Pi without having to use wifi, internet or data. My phone is rooted and is on Android 8.0. Any help would be great!

Comment: what does this even mean? .... `use my S7 as a display for my Pi`

Comment: @jsotola Samsung S7

Comment: Your title says "without WiFi", while the question body says "without ... internet or data". Does that mean that WiFi is either "Internet" or "data"?

Comment: I mean without an internet connection at all. No Wifi, Internet or mobile data.

Comment: Why not run an RDP client on your phone?

Comment: @kwasmich.   Can I do that without wifi?

Comment: Yes. But you will need additional hardware. Namely an USB to Ethernet adapter that fits into your phone (perhaps an USB to micro USB adapter as well) and a suitable ethernet cable.

Comment: It should also be possible using Bluetooth. But I never managed to get the network stack working in order to create a Bluetooth PAN.

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how to do either of those methods?

Comment: Yes, sure. As if there is a tutorial for everything. No, you have to collect all the pieces by yourself. Just take the hints I gave you and search for it. A quick search for `Android Ethernet` reveals some useful results [like this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uisnj8Xufp0). Next step would be to see if you can set up a static IP address on both devices. (spoiler: you can). Then you will have to find some RDP App for your phone. I am sure there are plenty.

Comment: I'm really new to this stuff. Seems like a lot of confusion to me. Maybe I'll just get a display instead.